# 'latency' does not exist in type 'MediaTrackConstraints'

Tags: javascript, typescript, webrtc, audio-streaming, mediastream

I am trying to add create audio stream using below code

```
const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: {
        noiseSuppression: false,
        echoCancellation: false,
        autoGainControl: false,
        latency: {
          ideal: 0,
        },
        deviceId,
      },
    });
```

I can typecast using any but don't want to typecast

```
const audioStream = await (navigator.mediaDevices as any).getUserMedia({
      audio: {
        noiseSuppression: false,
        echoCancellation: false,
        autoGainControl: false,
        latency: {
          ideal: 0,
        },
        deviceId,
      },
    })
```

But typescript is throwing error latency doesnot exist on MediaTrackConstraints, i used below documentation to add latency property in audio stream
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints

Comment: Wherever you got your types for MediaTrackConstraints are simply out-of-date.